# Replace text in the middle of a TextNode with an element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textnode

I want to insert html tags within a text node with TreeWalker, but TreeWalker forces my html brackets into & lt; & gt; no matter what I've tried. Here is the code:

```
var text;
var tree = document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while (tree.nextNode()) {
    text = tree.currentNode.nodeValue;
    text = text.replace(/(\W)(\w+)/g, '$1<element onmouseover="sendWord(\'$2\')">$2</element>');
    text = text.replace(/^(\w+)/, '<element onmouseover="sendWord(\'$1\')">$1</element>');
    tree.currentNode.nodeValue = text;
}
```

Using \< or " instead of ' won't help. My workaround is to copy all of the DOM tree to a string and to replace the html body with that. It works on very simple webpages and solves my first problem, but is a bad hack and won't work on anything more than a trivial page. I was wondering if I could just work straight with the text node rather than use a workaround. Here is the code for the (currently buggy) workaround:

```
var text;
var newHTML = "";
var tree = document.createTreeWalker(document.body);
while (tree.nextNode()) {
    text = tree.currentNode.nodeValue;
    if (tree.currentNode.nodeType == 3){
        text = text.replace(/(\W)(\w+)/g, '$1<element onmouseover="sendWord(\'$2\')">$2</element>');
        text = text.replace(/^(\w+)/, '<element onmouseover="sendWord(\'$1\')">$1</element>');
        }
    newHTML += text
}
document.body.innerHTML = newHTML;
```

Edit: I realize a better workaround would be to custom tag the text nodes ((Customtag_Start_Here) etc.), copy the whole DOM to a string, and use my customs tags to identify text nodes and modify them that way. But if I don't have to, I'd rather not.

Comment: You cannot inject HTML in a text node…

Comment: Could I tell the text node it doesn't want to be a text node anymore (i.e. tell it to have lots of text-node children)?

Comment: @e2r2i2k2 No. You can replace it, you can split it, but you can't change it.

Comment: Note that if you create new text nodes during walking you will then walk and visit them as well. Per my answer, it's simplest to instead gather all your text nodes and THEN walk them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To 'change' a text node into an element, you must [replace it with an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild). For example:

```
var text = tree.currentNode;
var el = document.createElement('foo');
el.setAttribute('bar','yes');
text.parentNode.replaceChild( el, text );
```

If you want to retain part of the text node, and inject an element "in the middle", you need to [create another text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) and [insert it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) and the element into the tree at the appropriate places in the tree.

---

**Edit**: Here's a function that might be super useful to you. :)

Given a text node, it runs a regex on the text values. For each hit that it finds it calls a custom function that you supply. If that function returns a string, then the match is replaced. However, if that function returns an object like:

```
{ name:"element", attrs{onmouseover:"sendWord('foo')"}, content:"foo" }
```

then it will split the text node around the match and inject an element in that location. You can also return an array of strings or those objects (and can recursively use arrays, strings, or objects as the `content` property).

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DpqGH/8/

```
function textNodeReplace(node,regex,handler) {
  var mom=node.parentNode, nxt=node.nextSibling,
      doc=node.ownerDocument, hits;
  if (regex.global) {
    while(node && (hits=regex.exec(node.nodeValue))){
      regex.lastIndex = 0;
      node=handleResult( node, hits, handler.apply(this,hits) );
    }
  } else if (hits=regex.exec(node.nodeValue))
    handleResult( node, hits, handler.apply(this,hits) );

  function handleResult(node,hits,results){
    var orig = node.nodeValue;
    node.nodeValue = orig.slice(0,hits.index);
    [].concat(create(mom,results)).forEach(function(n){
      mom.insertBefore(n,nxt);
    });
    var rest = orig.slice(hits.index+hits[0].length);
    return rest && mom.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode(rest),nxt);
  }

  function create(el,o){
    if (o.map) return o.map(function(v){ return create(el,v) });
    else if (typeof o==='object') {
      var e = doc.createElementNS(o.namespaceURI || el.namespaceURI,o.name);
      if (o.attrs) for (var a in o.attrs) e.setAttribute(a,o.attrs[a]);
      if (o.content) [].concat(create(e,o.content)).forEach(e.appendChild,e);
      return e;
    } else return doc.createTextNode(o+"");
  }
}
```

It's not quite perfectly generic, as it does not support namespaces on attributes. But hopefully it's enough to get you going. :)

---

You would use it like so:

```
findAllTextNodes(document.body).forEach(function(textNode){
  replaceTextNode( textNode, /\b\w+/g, function(match){
    return {
      name:'element',
      attrs:{onmouseover:"sendWord('"+match[0]+"')"},
      content:match[0]
    };
  });
});

function findAllTextNodes(node){
  var walker = node.ownerDocument.createTreeWalker(node,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
  var textNodes = [];
  while (walker.nextNode())
    if (walker.currentNode.parentNode.tagName!='SCRIPT')
      textNodes.push(walker.currentNode);
  return textNodes;
}
```

or if you want something closer to your original regex:

```
  replaceTextNode( textNode, /(^|\W)(\w+)/g, function(match){
    return [
      match[1], // might be an empty string
      {
        name:'element',
        attrs:{onmouseover:"sendWord('"+match[2]+"')"},
        content:match[2]
      }
    ];
  });
```

Comment: I see how this would be done now, but the above code spits out a very long 
`DomException....message: Node was not found` 
error. I'll keep toying with it to get it to work.

Comment: @e2r2i2k2 See my edit for a way to 'replace' text in text nodes with elements and have them automatically split for you. And be sure to see the demo URL for an application of it.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That function will have a lot for me to play with.
For your original code, I found the problem. The last line should read
`text.parentNode.replaceChild( el, text );`
The two node vars were reversed.

Comment: What if the parent of the textnode is coming null? How do I replace that textnode with an html element?

Answer (score 0):

Function that returns the parent element of any text node including partial match of passed string:

```
function findElByText(text, mainNode) {
    let textEl = null;
    const traverseNodes = function (n) {
        if (textEl) {
            return;
        }
        for (var nodes = n.childNodes, i = nodes.length; i--;) {
            if (textEl) {
                break;
            }
            var n = nodes[i], nodeType = n.nodeType;
            // Its a text node, check if it matches string
            if (nodeType == 3) {
                if (n.textContent.includes(text)) {
                    textEl = n.parentElement;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (nodeType == 1 || nodeType == 9 || nodeType == 11) {
                traverseNodes(n);
            }
        }
    }
    traverseNodes(mainNode);
    return textEl;
}
```

Usage:

```
findElByText('Some string in document', document.body);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31062247)